# Error while trying to import Array._ and import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was running below code,

```
import Array._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn(name, concat(substring(col(name),1,4),substring(col(name),6,2), substring(col(name),9,2) ))
```

and getting an import error,

```
Error:(188, 26) reference to concat is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import Array._
and import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
     df.withColumn(name, concat(substring(col(name),1,4),substring(col(name),6,2), substring(col(name),9,2) ))
```

How can I overcome this ? I need to use both the imports.

Comment: I would argue that `import Array._` is a bad practice, and I do not see any reason to justify its use.

Answer (score 1):

Scala `Array` [class contains method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#concat[B%3E:A](suffix:Array[_%3C:B])(implicitevidence$23:scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]):Array[B]) `concat`
and [spark sql object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#concat) `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` contains method `concat`
If you need to import both `concat`s use alias:

```
import Array.{concat => concatArray}
```